# Rails Sending photos with active storage to aws - not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Created an application that stores photos. It works fine locally. Now I would like to send admissions to awd. I already have a bucket and an aws account. Unfortunately, I am able to display the food on the website. The photo is not added to the aws website. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

storage.yml

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: us-east-2
  bucket: pp-as
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  #has_one_attached :photo
   has_one_attached :featured_image

  def featured_image_url
    if self.featured_image.attachment
      self.featured_image.attachment.service_url
    end
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: image, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if image.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% image.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :photo %>
    <%= form.file_field :featured_image %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :caption %>
    <%= form.text_area :caption %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @image.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Caption:</strong>
  <%= @image.caption %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to image_tag(:images_path_url), images_path %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_image_path(@image) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', images_path %>
```

credentials.yml.enc

```
AWSAccessKeyId= my asscessKeyId 
AWSSecretKey= my SecretKey
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the upload the images? Carrierwave? ActiveStorage?

Presuming it's Active Storage, have you configured your config/environments/production.rb?

If not, try:

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

[Source](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)